# AWS SNS SMS for Indian Numbers

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I'm using AWS SDK 3.0 to send SMS via AWS SNS for indian numbers. I've ec2 instance created on AWS.
Please refer the code below :

```
$params = array(
        'credentials' => array(
            'key' => 'XXXXXX',
            'secret' => 'XXXXXXX',
        ),
        'region' => 'us-west-2', // < your aws from SNS Topic region
        'version' => 'latest',
         'http' => [ 'verify' => false ]
    );
    $sns = new \Aws\Sns\SnsClient($params);

    $args = array(
        'MessageAttribute' => [
            'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID' => [
                'DataType'    => 'String',
                'StringValue' => 'Sender',
            ],
            'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType'  => [
                'DataType'    => 'String',
                'StringValue' => 'Transactional',
            ]
        ],
        "Message" => "Test Message",
        "PhoneNumber" => "+91XXXXXX",
        'MessageStructure' => 'string',
    );

    $result = $sns->publish($args);
```

This code is sending SMS. However, the SMS are getting logged as Promotional SMS instead of Transactional. Thus getting delivered between 9am to 8pm only.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your programming logic is fine. There is a typo in you script.It is ***MessageAttributes*** not *MessageAttribute*. Due to this typo, it is ignoring the Message attributes which you are passing and taking the `default message type` set in your `Text messaging preferences` section in SNS aws console which is `Promotional`.

**Correct Code:**

> ```
> $args = array(
>     'MessageAttributes' => [
>         'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID' => [
>             'DataType'    => 'String',
>             'StringValue' => 'Sender',
>         ],
>         'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType'  => [
>             'DataType'    => 'String',
>             'StringValue' => 'Transactional',
>         ]
>     ],
>     "Message" => "Test Message",
>     "PhoneNumber" => "+91XXXXXX",
>     'MessageStructure' => 'string',
> );
> ```